# How to get different breeds to be `ask`ed in a random order together

Tags: netlogo

Suppose we have two breeds, `cats` and `dogs`. On `go`, we want `cats` to `meow` and `dogs` to `bark`. `ask` causes the agents in the given agentset to run the code block in a random order, which is great. However, if we do:

```
to go
  ask cats [ meow ]
  ask dogs [ bark ]
  tick
end
```

`dogs` always go after `cats`. We could solve this problem with conditionals:

```
to go
  ask turtles [
    if breed = cats [ meow ]
    if breed = dogs [ bark ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

but this is gross (note that you can replace the `turtles` with `(turtle-set cats dogs)` for more complicated situations with breeds that you don't want mixed in). Any better solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use tasks:

```
turtles-own [noise]

to setup
  ...
  ask cats [ set noise task meow ]
  ask dogs [ set noise task bark ]
  ...
end

to go
  ...
  ask turtles [ run noise ]
  ...
end
```

Comment: This is kinda brilliant. It shows how NetLogo tasks can be used to implement polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

How about a shuffled list of paired agentsets and tasks?

```
to go
  let actions (list
    (list cats task meow)
    (list dogs task bark)
  )
  foreach shuffle actions [
    ask first ? [ run last ? ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas! This would still run cats all in one block, then dogs all in one block, though the technique could probably be modified to get them to intermix. Maybe generate two separate `(agent task)` lists (one for cats, one for dogs) with `of`, combine them with `sentence`, then proceed with the `foreach shuffle`.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was what you wanted (i.e., that your second code block was undesirable _because_ they intermixed). Sorry for misinterpreting your question. I'll leave my answer here in case it's still useful for someone.